# Combining dimensions in a Google Analytics report?

Tags: google-analytics

For each page view, I pass a bunch of custom dimensions. An article can be assigned up to three taxonomy terms, for sake of this question let's call them apples, oranges, and pears. They are never in the same order. So these are currently passed to GA in three separate dimensions. Article A might look like:

```
- Fruit1: apple
- Fruit2: pear
- Fruit3: orange
```

And article B might be:

```
- Fruit1: orange
- Fruit2: apple
- Fruit3: pear
```

Not to mention article C might look like:

```
- Fruit1: pear
- Fruit2: orange
- Fruit3: NULL (not passed)
```

So basically when I want to look at something like Page Views by Fruit, I would like to combine these metrics. Is there a way in GA to "sum up" the dimenions? In other words:

```
Pear = Sum of all page views where either Fruit1, Fruit2, OR Fruit3 = 'pear'
Apple = Sum of all page views where either Fruit1, Fruit2, OR Fruit3 = 'apple'
```

etc.

Comment: As I continue digging, I believe Segments might be the answer, but would still appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to sum up dimensions since dimensions are strings. If you want to sum up thing you'd have to use custom metrics. Create three custom metrics, send a value of 1 every time time one of your taxonomy term is set. GA will add each of those metrics up and you'll get the numbers you're after.